# Mark a collection of an entity to be reloaded

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6.1

I am using EF 6.1 to track changes to all objects inheriting from the abstract base class `HistoryData` and keep each of its `Versions` in a collection of a parent object.

They are hooked up like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .HasMany(f => f.Versions)
        .WithRequired(fv => fv.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(fv => fv.ParentID);
```

Instead of modifying an entry, I hook into the `DbContext` and do this:

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<HistoryData>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {
        InsertInsteadOfUpdate(entry);
    }
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private void InsertInsteadOfUpdate(DbEntityEntry<HistoryData> entry)
{
    // ValidFrom is not set manually -> Set it automatically to now
    if (entry.OriginalValues["ValidFrom"].Equals(entry.CurrentValues["ValidFrom"]))
    {
        entry.Entity.ValidFrom = DateTime.Now;
    }
    // Insert instead of Update
    entry.State = EntityState.Added;
}
```

This works fine so far and the entity is inserted instead of updated.

However, the new `HistoryData` entity is not loaded automatically when I call `Foo.Versions`.

So now I do something like this at the end of `InsertInsteadOfUpdate`:

```
    // Mark collection of parent as not loaded so that it gets lazy loaded on the next call
    var parent = entry.Reference("Parent").CurrentValue;
    Entry(parent).Collection("Versions").Load();
```

That works, but it reloads the Collection instantly. If I insert several `HistoryData` objects before querying `Versions`, this is a lot of unnecessary work.

All I really want to do is **mark the Collection() of the parent to be reloaded the next time I query it**. Is there some way to do this?

I tried

```
Entry(parent).Collection("Versions").IsLoaded = false;
```

but for some reason that did not cause the Collection to be lazy loaded on the next call.